# Choosing GPS app to use for mapping bus routes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps, software-recommendations, android

I am looking for a GPS app for android to capture waypoints and lines. I'm going to map the route buses and the stop points.

Which GPS app is recommended for marking “points” and marking the “lines”?

I'll be using it with ArcGIS in Brazil, South America.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Collector for ArcGIS**

Extend the reach of ArcGIS to your field workforce and use the Collector to improve the accuracy and currency of your spatial data. Using ArcGIS Online you can create and configure maps that tailor the ArcGIS collector to fit your workflow needs.

Features:
Collect and Update Spatial Data
* **Collect new GIS features using the map or GPS**
* Complete intelligent data entry forms specific to your data
* Attach photos

Find Places and get Directions
* Find places and points of interest around you
* Get driving directions to places and your features (via your ArcGIS Online Subscription)

Measure
* Calculate distance and area on top of the map

Location Tracking
* Periodically report your location

Map Viewing
* Open bookmarked locations
* Switch basemaps
* Turn on/off map layers

Available on the Play Store [Free]
Updated 23rd July 2014

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esri.arcgis.collector&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

TransitWand is an open source web and mobile application for collecting transit data. Use it to create GTFS feeds, capture passenger counts or generate GIS datasets

Check out the web site [here](http://transitwand.com/)